# Compare 2 fields in Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I want to do a simple SQL query in Drupal, but I'm not sure how. I would like to achieve this:

```
SELECT COUNT(nid) AS i_count FROM node WHERE `created` != `changed`;
```

I have the following code, which doesn't work:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->addExpression("COUNT(nid)","i_count");
$query->condition("created","changed","!=");
$i_number_published = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

The reason why it doesn't work is that it compares the column `created` with the string value `"changed"`. Is there any way I can tell it to compare columns instead of column-string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `where()` member function to add conditions based on other fields in the table:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->addExpression("COUNT(nid)","i_count");
$query->where("created != changed");
$i_number_published = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know there was a `where` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_handler = db_query("select count(nid) from {node} where `created` != `changed`") ; 

$result_arr = db_fetch_array($result_handler) ; 

$number_of_nodes = $result_arr['count(nid)'] ;
```